# if size of computer address is 7 bit, what is maximum size of memory address space in computer like that?

Tags: memory, memory-management, bit

I have never see 7 bit computer. My professor asked this question and no one knew it.
So how is this calculating?
I translated the question form Croatian so it may be little confusing.
**Thank you!**

Comment: there is the 4004 which is a 4-bit computer

Comment: Well, if a 32 bit processor (theoretically) can address 4 GB ...

Comment: Than answer should be 2^7 that is 128 Bytes, right, if 2^32 is 4GB. @Filburt

Comment: I guess your professor was just teasing you with wikipedia trivia.

Comment: @Legenda321: Indeed but beware that a `byte` could be of arbitrary length and so the memory space won't necessarily be 128x8 bits, in fact I'd be mildly surprised if it was for any extant computer systems with 7-bit address spaces.